# MS SQL Server - Cursor inside cursor taking long time

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE TEST
AS
    DECLARE @text_var nvarchar(200),
            @num_var numeric(27, 4);

    DECLARE c_cur1 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2
               textID
        FROM text_table
        WHERE status = 'Approved';

    OPEN c_cur1;

    FETCH NEXT FROM c_cur1
    INTO @text_var;

    WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN

        PRINT 'first cursor: ' + @text_var;

        DECLARE c_cur2 CURSOR FOR
            SELECT TOP 1
                   numID
            FROM num_table
            WHERE text = @text_var
            ORDER BY cdate DESC;

        PRINT 'before opening second cursor';

        OPEN c_cur2;

        FETCH NEXT FROM c_cur2
        INTO @num_var;

        WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
        BEGIN

            PRINT 'Inside second cursor' + @text_var;

        END;

        CLOSE c_cur2;

        DEALLOCATE c_cur2;

        FETCH NEXT FROM c_cur1
        INTO @text_var;

    END;

    CLOSE c_cur1;

    DEALLOCATE c_cur1;
```

The text "Inside second cursor" is getting printed quite a few times (should be more than 1000 times at least), while I believe it should be only twice.

As a result this query is taking at least 30 mins to run.

Kindly suggest if there is anything wrong in the above code

Comment: The problem is probably that you are using a `CURSOR`. You're thinking programmatically. SQL isn't a programming language, it's a query language. You needs to think what do you want to do to a column; not what do you want to do to a row.

Comment: Do you have an index on the `num_table` `text` column? Is the data type  `nvarchar(200)` to match the variable?

Comment: Instead of just posting your code, provide us with some sample data, and expected results, and explain your goal I am 99% sure that there will be a dataset based solution, that will be significantly faster.

Comment: Cursors are occasionally necessary (we can't tell if that's the case here since we can't see the innermost statement) but nested cursors have almost no reason to exist. You're effectively writing out a `JOIN` with imperative code. Even if the use of a cursor was absolutely necessary here, you could have the cursor go through the results of a `JOIN` between `text_table` and `num_table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that it is looping to often is because you have misplaced your `fetch next from c_cur2. It should go inside the BEGIN..END block associated with the relevant WHILE as below. As it is, you are causing an infinite loop.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST AS

DECLARE @text_var nvarchar(200), @num_var numeric(27,4)

DECLARE c_cur1 CURSOR for select distinct top 2 textID from text_table where status = 'Approved';

open c_cur1

fetch next from c_cur1 into @text_var

    While @@fetch_status = 0 
    BEGIN

        PRINT 'first cursor: ' + @text_var

        declare c_cur2 CURSOR for select top 1 numID from num_table where text = @text_var order by cdate desc;

        PRINT 'before opening second cursor'

        open c_cur2
        fetch next from c_cur2 into @num_var    
        while @@fetch_status = 0

        BEGIN

            PRINT 'Inside second cursor' + @text_var
            fetch next from c_cur2 into @num_var
        END

        CLOSE c_cur2

        DEALLOCATE c_cur2

        FETCH NEXT FROM c_cur1 INTO @text_var

    END

CLOSE c_cur1

DEALLOCATE c_cur1
```

Although fine for learning purposes, cursors should be replaced by a set based solution.